# How run all tests for class in Intellij Idea?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, run-configuration

I can open a java class in Intellij Idea, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> and see list with test classes associated with the class. Is there a way to run all tests in this list?
**P.S.**
Without opening run configuration window and manually adding all classes with copy pasting class names.

Comment: Did you mean Ctrl+Shift+T? I believe you can select multiple test from the list and do Shift+F10 to run them.

Comment: Yes this is the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The test can be run with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>. Thanks to *denis.solonenko* comment.

**UPDATED**
You also make sure that pop-up window after <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> is active. :-)